# What is this? Is this malware?

Tags: malware, firefox

My Firefox history shows "crypto.stamford.edu/flashproxy/embed.html?debug" every time I log on. I've never to my knowledge used any sites connected to Stamford university - can anyone tell me what this is?

Comment: Flash Proxy is a plugin similar to Tor activity. Check your plugin list.

Comment: Almost certainly not. That's the Stamford Cryptography course website, an open and free course for people who want to learn about crypto.

Comment: @Polynomial, check [this](https://crypto.stanford.edu/flashproxy/). Especially the URL.

Comment: @Emadeddin The "almost certainly not" was aimed at the OP, not you. Flash Proxy is a project created by Stamford, and they operate their crypto course on the same domain.

Comment: "Stamford" or "Stanford"?

Comment: https://crypto.stanford.edu/flashproxy/, it seems like you are used as a proxy.

https://crypto.stanford.edu/flashproxy/flashproxy.pdf